# How to do DependsOn in aws-cdk-python

Tags: python, devops, aws-cdk, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to create a documentDB along with db-instance. Both functions are in the same stack class, But when i try to run the code, the instance and db cluster start creating parallel and throws an error that cluster_name not found for instance creation.

I want to know is there any method like dependsOn in aws cdk.
something like this is js: **dbInstance.addDependsOn(dbCluster);**

Answer (score 0):

In AWS CDK Python, we can create a dependency between resources using the **add_depends_on** method. This method allows you to specify the dependencies between resources so that AWS CDK can create or update them in the correct order.

Something like this:

```
    bucket = s3.Bucket(self, "MyBucket")

    queue = sqs.Queue(self, "MyQueue")

    # Add a dependency from the SQS queue to the S3 bucket
    queue.add_depends_on(bucket)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to use `.node.add_dependency(resource_object)`

But I was using a custom resource as the dependent object.